# airodump-ng mon0 detects ips but doesnt show root@kali:~# so i can proceed

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, vmware-workstation

CH  5 ][ Elapsed: 50 mins ][ 2015-03-29 19:17

BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID

-47     1579     924    0   1  54e  WPA2   CCMP   PSK default

-88     608      133    0   13 54e WPA2    CCMP   PSK PintzK

BSSID             STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe

-61    0e- 1      0    1013   Default

i am not getting root@kali :~# though its been 50 min, so i can proceed with "airodump-ng -c - w mon0 mac"

chipset aetheros (TP-LINK WN722N) , win 7, 32bit vmware wrk station 10 debian

Comment: It would help if you included a few actual sentences describing your problem.  There are only a handful of words interspersed in this gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Unix commands are designed to run indefinitely until stopped with Ctrl-C.

Comment: Thank you sir ..done..! I got a little question will my neighbour get to know if i crack his wep or wpa2.?